# Updating array elements that matches a specific criteria

Tags: rethinkdb

Let's say I have the following array

`var data = [{ id: 0, points: 1 }, { id: 1, points: 2 }]`

I would like to update my table which contains

`{
  "doc-1": {
    "id": "abcxyz123",
    "entries": [
      { "id": 0, "points": 5 },
      { "id": 1, "points": 3 },
      { "id": 2, "points": 0 }
    ]
  }
}`

so that I add the points-field in the data array to the points-field for each element in the "entries" array in "doc-1" that matches the corresponding id in the data array. The end result would look like:

`{
  "doc-1": {
    "id": "abcxyz123",
    "entries": [
      { "id": 0, "points": 6 },
      { "id": 1, "points": 4 },
      { "id": 2, "points": 0 }
    ]
  }
}`

How do I go about to write such a query in ReQL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that the actual document in the table looks like this for now:

```js
{
  "id": "abcxyz123",
  "entries": [{
    "id": 0,
    "points": 5
  }, {
    "id": 1,
    "points": 3
  }, {
    "id": 2,
    "points": 0
  }]
}
```

That is without the `doc-1` nesting.

Then your update can be done like this:

```js
r.table('t1').update(
  {
    entries: r.row('entries').map(function(e) {
      return r.do(r.expr(data)('id').indexesOf(e('id')), function(dataIndexes) {
        return r.branch(
          dataIndexes.isEmpty(),
          e,
          {
            id: e('id'),
            points: e('points').add(r.expr(data)(dataIndexes(0))('points'))
          });
      });
    })
  })
```

I'm using `map` to map over each entry in `entries`, and `indexesOf` to find the corresponding entry in `data` if it exists.

Note that this doesn't add new entries to the `entries` list, but only updates existing ones. Please let me know if you need to add new entries as well.

If your documents actually have the `doc-1` field first, this query should do the job:

```js
r.table('t1').update(
  { 'doc-1':
    {
      entries: r.row('doc-1')('entries').map(function(e) {
        return r.do(r.expr(data)('id').indexesOf(e('id')), function(dataIndexes) {
          return r.branch(
            dataIndexes.isEmpty(),
            e,
            {
              id: e('id'),
              points: e('points').add(r.expr(data)(dataIndexes(0))('points'))
            });
        });
      })
    }
  })
```